# Vertically center image on navigation bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: My objective]

I'm trying to do a navigation bar in CSS with two buttons on the left side and one image on the right. The problem is that **my image has to fit the size of the navigation bar**, and at the same time, **it has to be vertically centered**. If anyone could help me solve this, I would be truly glad.

**Solution:** I ended up solving it by using **"flex"** and **"margin"** (the navigation bar display property was set to flex and the icon margin-left was set to auto, making it go to the right of the flex row). Here is a code example: `https://jsfiddle.net/572bag0z/#&togetherjs=QJn2LqjxTQ`

```
.top-nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    align-items: center;
    height: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 .5px 4px;
}
.top-nav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2em;
}
.top-nav img {
    width: 3em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: .75em;
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Post a code example. I use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I ended up solving it by using "flex" and "margin" (setting the margin-left of the icon to auto). Here is a code example of what I did https://jsfiddle.net/572bag0z/#&togetherjs=QJn2LqjxTQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally and historically, centering elements along the vertical axis has been a pain. Things have gotten much better though, and now there are some pretty easy ways to about it. I'd recommend looking into using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)'s `align-items` property.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you say, the vertical axis has always been a pain and flexbox has come to solve our suffering. 
Again, thank you bro!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way of doing this is adding
`margin-top:auto; margin-botom:auto;` to the img and `display:flex;` or `display: grid;` to the container. It wouldn't work without flex or grid.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/thescv/pen/YzqrLeK